# Using BackgroundWorker to update main form UI with FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm a little stuck attempting to use a BackgroundWorker to update my main form UI in response to a FileSystemWatcher event being fired.

1. FileSystemWatcher checks for an image being added to a specific folder, fires OnCreated Handler
2. OnCreated handler calls RunWorkerAsync(e.FullPath) to pass the filename to the background worker
3. Background worker RunWorkerAsync taks the file path, and adds the item to a List(Of Product)
4. List(Of Product) gets added to a ListBox control on the main UI

My first issue, is updating the main UI thread after the background worker is complete. I process the image in a background worker as it takes a few seconds to generate a thumbnail from the image and don't want to lock the UI.

My second issue I'm running into, is after my event fires the second time, and exception gets thrown that the background worker is busy.

```
Private HoldingTank As New List(Of Product)

Private Sub LoadImages()
    Me.ToolStripStatusLabelUpdate.Text = "Images Loading - Please Wait...."
    CheckedListBoxView.Items.Clear()
    HoldingTank = Me.CreateImageList()
    For Each product As Product In HoldingTank
        Me.CheckedListBoxView.Items.Add(New ListViewDataItem With {.Image = product.Image, .ImageAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, .Tag = product})
    Next
    Me.ToolStripStatusLabelUpdate.Text = "Ready"
End Sub

Public Sub WatchFolders()
    watcher.Path = PathImport
    watcher.Filter = "*.tif"
    AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf OnCreated
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

 Sub OnCreated(sender As Object, e As IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(e.FullPath)
 End Sub

 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_LoadImages(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
     HoldingTank.Add(New Product() With {.FileName = path.getFileName(e.argument), .FileExtension = path.GetExtension(e.argument), .FileFullPath = e.argument, .Image = GenerateThumbnail(e.argument)})
     '// Function GenerateThumbnail returns an Image object
End Sub
```

1. How can i update the CheckedListBoxView control once the BackgroundWorker has added the item to the list without getting an illegal cross-thread call?
2. How can i check if the worker is busy if another file event raises, before the worker completes?

Comment: You have explicitly asked two different questions, which is explicitly against the rules. If you have two questions then create two questions. You can hardly accept a single answer for two separate questions unless one person addresses both of them. Please follow the rules.

Comment: The 2nd question doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, make sure that you have set the `SynchronizingObject` property of the `FileSystemwatcher`. If you haven't, it will raise its events on a secondary thread, which you do not want in this case. You should assign the form to that property.

Secondly, you do NOT touch the UI in the `DoWork` event handler or any method called from it. That is all executing on a secondary thread and you can't modify the UI on any but the UI thread. You do all the work you can in the `DoWork` event handler and then assign the resulting data to the `e.Result` property.

You then handle the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, which is executed on the UI thread, get that data back from the `e.Result` property and then update the UI. I don't know exactly what control you're using there but you should be able to create the items on the secondary thread but you'll then need to add them to the control on the UI thread.

You can find my own `BackgroundWorker` examples [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889).

Comment: VbForums with an error message of `PHP User Warning: fetch_template() calls should be replaced by the vB_Template class. Template name: bbcode_highlight in ..../includes/functions.php on line 4197`. *That's* showing confidence in the technology the forum is about :)

Comment: @AndrewMorton, they have a custom add-in for vBulletin that provides syntax highlighting for code snippets that always needed manual attention every time the site software was upgraded and the latest vBulletin update caused that due to some incompatibility. The site admins have repeatedly pushed the issue up the chain but the site owners seem unwilling to address it. Everything still seems to work well enough except pages with `highlight` tags in posts show those error and posts containing those tags try to submit twice.